# MSSQL Sorting DB products Daily

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, casting

I have an MSSQL DataBase with a good amount of products that i would like to seemly randomize their order by each day!

> So when i query my DB, the products will look in a **randomize order
>   but persistent for each day of the week**.
>
> For example: I have 10.000 products of a specific category. Each user
>   should see the same products in this category with the same order. Top
>   20 products should stay the same through the day for every user that
>   is visiting this category. So the problem is that the users will not
>   scroll enough to see the last products in this category. So I would
>   like to "shuffle" the products ones per day so more products of the
>   specific category will be shown to my returning visitors.

So at my DB i generate a field like so:

```
(ABS(REVERSE(CAST(CAST(Product_id AS VARBINARY) AS INT))) * CAST(DATEPART ( "weekday" , getdate()) as INT)) as [dailysort]
```

- I use REVERSE because my product ids are serialized e.g 455606371,
  455606377, 455606379 e.t.c
- I get the weekday (1 - 7) and multiply it by the REVERSED product_id
- I use ABS to make sure my result is a positive number
- I order my query by [dailysort]
- Probably i use CAST too much

So by reversing and multiplying it seems i have the best chances of getting a unique random list for each day of the week.

> My question is:
>
> 1. How safe is this
> 2. Where can this fail
> 3. Any better approach

*Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated*

Comment: What an odd requirement...

Comment: I'd do this in the front end tbh, using a random number generator seeded with the year-week

Comment: What does "randomize order but persistent for each day of the week" mean?  Sample data and results would really help.

Comment: For every Sunday you want the same sort at it was the last Sunday, or a new sort that would just last this entire day?

Comment: @Zohar, at the moment as i have formed my [dailysort], Sunday will have always the same sort. it would be even better to have completely different sort for each day. So maybe I could use the 'day' instead 'weekday' from datepart. but i'm afraid that it would effect performance & maybe fail. So yes: Just a sort that would last this entire day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a `Created_date` column for your products.

I would use that with a modulo or division operator along with `DAY(GETDATE())` to "build" my one-day caching algorithm.

So, my `ORDER BY` would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    DAY(CREATED_DATE) / DAY(GETDATE()) [Sorting]
...
ORDER BY Sorting
```

In this way, the sorting will vary each day and give the same results when queried daily.

**Update 1:**

In case you have the same result for overlapping results (products added in the same day but different months), you can also extend this to add more variability:

```
SELECT
    DAY(CREATED_DATE) % DAY(GETDATE())       [DSorting]
    , MONTH(CREATED_DATE) % MONTH(GETDATE()) [MSorting]
...
ORDER BY DSorting
    , MSorting
```

**Update 2:**

However you still don't have a 100% deterministic approach with my previous answer, so I'd suggest to add some uniqueness to the `ORDER BY` by including your PK column (assuming you have one), like below:

```
SELECT
    DAY(CREATED_DATE) % DAY(GETDATE())       [DSorting]
    , MONTH(CREATED_DATE) % MONTH(GETDATE()) [MSorting]
...
ORDER BY DSorting
    , MSorting
    , ProductID    -- most common PK column name I have ever seen
```

**Update 3:**

After your comment, I believe it would be sufficient to replace the `CREATED_DATE` with `Product_ID` so you would get to something like:

```
SELECT
    Product_ID % DAY(GETDATE())      [DSorting]
    , Product_ID % MONTH(GETDATE())  [MSorting]
...
ORDER BY DSorting
    , MSorting
    , Product_ID
```

Comment: Hi @Radu, Thanks for the suggestion! This looks promising but my [inserted] field is mostly the same for all the products in the category (BULK INSERT) so the only field that could be useful to create a sense of randomness would be the product_id. :)

Comment: @Alex So, then you could use the `PRODUCT_ID` column instead of `DAY(CRATED_DATE)` and `MONTH(Created_Date)`. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: just tested and I get 0 on every single line of [DSorting] and [MSorting]. maybe instead of modulus (%) division seems to work better!

Answer (score 0):

> randomize order but persistent for each day of the week.

I don't know what this is supposed to mean.  I might interpret this as "random within each day, but the days in a fixed order".  If so, perhaps two keys do what you want:

```
order by datepart(weekday, getdate()),
         newid()
```

Comment: @Alex Then just remove the `newid()` call from the `ORDER BY`. That should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks for the suggestion. newid() will give you a new id every time you query the products (The order should be persistent for all users). Every user should be able to see the same ordered results for each day but new order for every next day. (Think of it like 1 day caching)